# Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult - Facebook SDK Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

My Dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:11.0.0'
}
```

I've been using a `LoginButton` for moths without any problem but since today after call to  `login` if the users have not logged before in my app the login flow seems to works fine but the `onError` method of my `FacebookCallback` is called and I have the next error `Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult` and the second time that I call `login` it works and I don't have the `Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult` error.

---

Here the complete code of my Activity

```java
package app.meedu.flutter_facebook_auth;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LoginButton  button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        button.setPermissions("public_profile,email");
        button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                Log.i("GOOD::","exito");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.i("ERROR::",exception.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project might be in development mode, switch to live mode might solve the problem

Comment: this should be a comment